# How to add partial morphology to image with help of opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image which could be shadowed in some parts, and bright in some others. It consists of black and white (or between) colors.

[image]

I was wondering how to apply morphology effect on it so that in parts which are dark, the light colors get more notice, and in parts which is bright, the dark colors become bolder.

What I have seen so far, only applies the same morphological effect on whole picture.

Comment: your picture looks okay. you don't need that there. approach to "even out" illumination: calculate gaussian blur or other blur (median?), subtract that, add some constant back, and make sure you are handling integer over/underflow to your satisfaction and that you don't run into saturation math.

Comment: I am a bit new to this stuff, so could you give me an example of what you mean?